# Proving the cardinality of an unknown set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let A be a finite set with m elements, for some m ∈ N. And suppose x is an object that is not a member of A.
Prove, using the definitions, that A ∪ {x} has m + 1 elements by showing that there is a bijection from **N**m+1 (the set of the first m+1 natural numbers) to A ∪ {x}

I have no idea how to show injective or surjective given no information about A.

Comment: You *do* have information about $A\!:$ it's a finite set with $m$ elements, where $m\in\mathbb{N}.$

Comment: but how do you use that to show injection/surjection

Comment: Define $g$ as in @MikePierce's answer.   Show that $g$ is 1-1 using the definition of 1-1, and show that $g$ is onto using the definition of onto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $|A| = m$, there exists a bijection $f\colon A \to \{1, \dotsc, m\}$. So just define a function 
$$
  g \colon \left(A\cup\{x\}\right)\to\{1, \dotsc, m, m+1\}
$$
$$
  g(n) = \begin{cases}f(n)\;\;\quad\text{if}\;\; n\in A\\m+1\quad \text{if}\;\;n=x\end{cases}
$$

and show that $g$ is a bijection.

Comment: how do you show that _g_ is a bijection with that information??

Comment: @Sid Show it's injective and surjective.